# How to set function on button click in js file

Tags: reactjs

I have a react template, where there is a button and i want to call function on button click.
below is my js file and it gives error as handlesubmit is not defined.
import React from "react";

```
<Button
                        block
                        className="btn-round"
                        color="info"
                        href="#pablo"
                        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                        size="lg"
                      >
                        Verify text
                      </Button>
```

attaching image for code[image]

Comment: can you share all lines of code in your file ?

Comment: onClick={this.handleSubmit} Isn't this working?

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: no its nt working

Comment: i am getting error   Line 39:3:  'handleSubmit' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: post ur full code here

Comment: edited my question ..pls chk now

Comment: Please **Do Not** post screenshot of your code, post the code instead. That helps those who tries to help you by answering your question.

Comment: it was nt allowing me to post. that why posted screnshot

Answer (score 6):

You are using a functional component, so you cannot use state inside a functional component. And next, try giving onClick={handleSubmit} and report if it is working.

Comment: its nt working..still giving error as handlesubmit is nt defined

Answer (score 0):

Check that the function named **handleSubmit** is inside the function where you have coded the button tag and use `onClick={handleSubmit}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function handleSubmit() {
   // e.preventDefault();    
    //e.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/check', {
      method: 'POST',
     // body: this.state,
 

         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
    
          body: JSON.stringify({ post: this.state.post }),
    
        });
    
        const body = await response.text();
        this.setState({ responseToPost: body });
      };
```

This fixed my issue